# SQL Divide a field If

Tags: sql, divide

I'm trying to build a query to get the minimum stock of X components from an article. Imagine a computer, it has rams, motherboard, etc etc.
I can get the min component quantity easily, however, we usually place 2 RAM's in the computer we want to build, so, I want the query to get the StockValue of the RAMs/2.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT A1.Artigo AS Artigo,
       A1.Descricao AS Descricao,
       MIN(AA.StkActual) AS Stock,
       0 AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes,
       'Componente Stock' AS Id
FROM Artigo A1
     INNER JOIN ComponentesArtigos CA ON CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
     INNER JOIN Artigo A2 ON A2.Artigo = CA.Componente
                         AND (A2.Familia = 98
                           OR A2.Familia = 45
                           OR A2.Familia = 39
                           OR A2.Familia = 37
                           OR A2.Familia = 38)
     INNER JOIN ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo
                                AND AA.Armazem = 'A7'
GROUP BY A1.Artigo,
         A1.Descricao
HAVING A1.Artigo = '0180005132';
```

Things you need to know:
min(AA.StkActual) is the StockValue I'm talking about.
The RAM's are defined by family (A2.Familia = 39)

I don't want to divide the result of the query by 2, I want to divide the stock of the component/article which family = 39 by 2

Comment: What is your input and expected output ?

Comment: SQL Server <> MtySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: Where are you storing the number of RAM sticks? Seems like it would just be `MIN(AA.StkActual) / (RamSticks*1.0)`

Comment: Also, why all those `OR` clauses and not an `IN` expression (`A2.Familia IN (37.38.39.45.98)`)?

Comment: @xXx It seems like Gordon got me the solution, thanks anyway guys!

Comment: @Larnu honestly? Because I'm getting into an old's team project and I also suck at SQL. I've changed those OR clauses into an IN expression like you said! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a conditional minimum:

```
SELECT A1.Artigo AS Artigo,
       A1.Descricao AS Descricao,
       MIN(CASE WHEN A2.familia = 38 THEN AA.StkActual / 2 ELSE AA.StkActual END) AS Stock,
       0 AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes,
       'Componente Stock' AS Id
. . .
```

Comment: Checkpoint! Thanks Gordon, I've been struggling a bit with this query and voila, you solved it!

Comment: I have another question Gordon, I think you might know how to help me.... When the component is from A2.Familia = 98, I want it to get the stock value only of one AA.Armazem.

Imagine AA.Armazem 'A7' has 150 products, A8 has 0 and A9 has 8 products
How can I consider A7 first, then A8, then A9? I only want it to get the stock of 1 AA.Armazem, and then switches to the other if that one is 0.

In this case, If A7 = 0, A8= 0, then it will consider the stockValue of A9, otherwise, I want it to consider the AA.Armazem A7 stock since it still has units

Comment: @TiagoCosta . . . I think you should ask another question.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's what I did. If possible, check it.. I won't post the link here since I don't know if I should, so I guess you can see it on my profile.
Thanks for the help Gordon.